# Appending array objects to array objects in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am building a powershell tool for monitoring memory and cpu usage of a single process. I get the information i need using the following two lines:

```
$CPUSamples = (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$MEMSamples = Get-Process $ProcessName | Measure-Object Workingset -sum -average
```

$CPUSamples |Select-Object * gives the following output:

```
Path             : \\nibblerone\process(xmrig)\% processor time
InstanceName     : xmrig
CookedValue      : 2265,34873231763
RawValue         : 20688761250000
SecondValue      : 132626097939965662
MultipleCount    : 1
CounterType      : Timer100Ns
Timestamp        : 2021-04-11 12:16:33
Timestamp100NSec : 132626169939960000
Status           : 0
DefaultScale     : 0
TimeBase         : 10000000
```

$MEMSamples gives the following output:

```
Count    : 1
Average  : 19464192
Sum      : 19464192
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : WorkingSet
```

I would like to combine the two in an array using:

```
$Samples +=$CPUSamples | Select-Object *
$Samples += $MEMSamples
```

so that i can use something like the following line to get the data i want into a table.

```
$Samples| Select-Object InstanceName, @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}},Count, @{Name="SumMB";Expression = {[math]::round($_.Sum/1MB,2)}}
```

The output is as follows:

```
InstanceName CPU % Count SumMB
------------ ----- ----- -----
xmrig        96,23           0
                 0 1     18,57
```

I guess that i don't append the two arrays properly and thus i get two lines.
My desired output is as follows:

```
InstanceName CPU % Count SumMB
------------ ----- ----- -----
xmrig        96,23    1  18,57
```

Any ideas how i could fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Will there ever only be one instance of the process your searching for? If not, are you okay with combining the measurements from each, or do you need separate measurements per process?

Comment: How are you combining `$CPUSamples` and `$MEMSamples` ?

Comment: _"combine the two in an array"_ -- it looks like you are confusing arrays with objects, which makes this question hard to understand. From the desired output and the code sample what you would like to be able to do, you want to "merge" the properties of the two objects `$CPUSamples` and `$MEMSamples` in a new object?

Comment: Merging arrays of objects is generally done with a `for` loop using the array with highest number of objects to iterate. inside the loop you can combine both using a `pscustomobject`

Comment: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1